# Building a low-cost oscilloscope and a function generator

Tags: circuit-design, oscilloscope, function-generator

I want to build an oscilloscope and a function generator as a graduation project in my university. Cost should not exceed 125$ or 250$ if the project has more additional features. I will display outputs on a computer screen. I want resources to know what I'm going to do. Please give me as many resources and advices as you can.
Here are the specifications required:

[image]

Comment: Your labour rate must be nearly cents a day.

Comment: For what frequency range ? For very low frequencies, less than 100 kHz maybe 1 MHz material cost: no problem. Anything decent like above 10 MHz: the cost of the component(boards) will easily exceed your budget.

Comment: @Andyaka the mentioned cost is for components only.

Comment: @FakeMoustache Sorry I added the required specifications.

Comment: @Andyaka " ... as a graduation project in my university ..." -> labour rate is negative

Comment: A number of suitably fast microcontrollers can handle that. 20 uS sample time at 8 bits is "easy". Some may have 10 kB RAM but if not writing to external memory is again "easy". The rest is programming.

Comment: The Sainsmart oscilloscope kit manages 200khz bandwidth, and a sample rate like 1MHz, parts cost is about $20

Comment: @Jasen Is there a tutorial on how to build an oscilloscope like the Sainsmart one? Does Sainsmart provide information about how their oscilloscope is built?

Comment: It saddens me that this is a _graduation project_ and you come in here with the broadest possible question of "what kind of stuff should I look into". That isn't graduation level thinking, not by a mile.

Comment: @Asmyldof I understand your point but I actually have begun building my project. I've read many researches and I finished many stages of the project. I meant to have some helpful advices and maybe some new ideas to improve my work (which I think I got some). Maybe I didn't use the right words. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3):

> Please give me as many resources and advices as you can.

See below

> I will display outputs on a computer screen.

Use a sound card to capture waveforms - it won't work with DC signals but will work from 20 Hz to 20 kHz at normal sampling rates. You can also generate waveforms from software by creating wave files that can be outputted from the sound card.

The only hardware extras you will need is a front-end for the scope part that can handle 24Vp-p and a back end for the function generator that turns the line-out signal to 24Vp-p.

You get at least two input channels on a sound card so weight that against it not working at DC.

Comment: There are many software-only PC sound-card solutions such as [this one](http://www.zelscope.com/index.html) already. If decided to go this route, note that [RIFF .WAV data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAV) has some significant complexity across devices, so coding skill should address this to ensure compatibility.

Comment: @rdtsc did you not see in my answer where I said "The only hardware extras you will need is a front-end for the scope part that can handle 24Vp-p and a back end for the function generator that turns the line-out signal to 24Vp-p."

Comment: If you decide to use your sound card as an oscilloscope, then you could actually measure DC with the methods described by Asmyldof (in response to an earlier question by me) http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/180135/79572 Recommended reading!